# Python tkinter Menu

Tags: python, tkinter

I was taking a python course from Udemy and when I reached the GUI Programming, I came across menu. When I was writing code, it does not seem to work even though it is the same code as the tutorial.

```
from tkinter import *

def function1():
    print("Menu Item Clicked")

root = Tk()

mymenu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=mymenu)

submenu = Menu(mymenu)

mymenu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=submenu)

submenu.add_command(label="Project", command= function1)
submenu.add_command(label="Save", command = function1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: How does it not work? Do you get an error?

Comment: Generally importing like that is not advised (`from tkinter import *`). I'm not sure why all the tkinter docs/tutorials insist on that though.

Comment: Why do you think it's not working? It seems to work as expected. When I select either menu item, something is printed to stdout.

Comment: The code runs just fine. A window pops out, but there is supposed to be a file menu, which is not there. I tried running it in idle and PyCharm. Doesn't seem to work on both.

Comment: Are you running on OSX? On OSX the menu appears like with any other OSX application -- along the top of the display rather than on top of the window.

Comment: Thank You so much. I never realized that. I have been scratching my head over this all night.